# Python supposed to return str returns 'None'

Tags: python, function, return

I am working on a hangman program (it is a homework assignment) and this is the part where it tell the player what they have guessed so far. Here is my programming:

```
def getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
theWord=''
for char in secretWord:
    if char not in lettersGuessed:
        char='_ '
        theWord+=char
    elif char in lettersGuessed:
        theWord+=char
    else:
        return theWord
print (getGuessedWord('apple', ['e', 't', 'i', 'p', 'r']
```

When I ask it to print out `theWord` I am expecting it to send out a combination of underscores and letters `_ pp_ e`, but instead is gives me `None`. I cannot figure out if my problem is where I placed `theWord` in line 2, or if it has to do with the else, or if it somewhere completely different.

Comment: When do you expect that `else` to execute? What value would `char` have where `char not in lettersGuessed` is False _and_ `char in lettersGuessed` is False?

Comment: Is this exactly your code? It has whitespace errors.

Comment: Your return statement is misplaced, it should be after the for loop.

Comment: Your `for` loop must have ended without hitting the 2nd `else` clause inside. you'd probably need to `return theEord` at the end of your func?

Comment: 1) Please fix your indentation.  2) `theWord` is returned exactly if `char` is in `lettersGuessed` and `char` is not in `lettersGuessed` which is equivalent to never. E.g. your `else` block never runs.  Remove the `else` and dedent `return theWord` two levels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to `return` something after successful execution of the entire for-loop:

```
def getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
   theWord=''
   for char in secretWord:
      if char not in lettersGuessed:
         char='_ '
         theWord+=char
      elif char in lettersGuessed:
         theWord+=char
   return theWord #here, returning theWord
print (getGuessedWord('apple', ['e', 't', 'i', 'p', 'r']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just erase this else and fix the indentation. Like this:

```
def getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed): 
    theWord=''
    for char in secretWord:
        if char not in lettersGuessed:
            char='_ '
            theWord+=char
        elif char in lettersGuessed:
            theWord+=char
    return theWord

print (getGuessedWord('apple', ['e', 't', 'i', 'p', 'r']
```

Actualy your function is returning nothing. It's because your return is never called. You just don't enter in this else. You wrote a if in statement and an elif not in, it means you covered all cases in these two statements, then have no sense write an else.